# Is PHP capable of reading/writing to character devices in linux? (like /dev/i2c-1 on Raspberry Pi OS)

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, i2c

I have read [this article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021394/what-is-a-character-device) about "character devices" in linux. They are not normal block files.

After that I felt the need to read/write characters to this kind of devices in Linux with the PHP Client.

Got some of these devices on my Raspberry Pi at /dev directory (eg. /dev/i2c-1), so I tried

```
$address = 0x62;
$registry = 0x00;
$length = 1;

$address = ($address | 0x01) << 8 & $registry;
$i2c = fopen("/dev/i2c-1", "w+b");
fseek($i2c, $address);
$rtn = fread($i2c, $length);
echo $rtn;
fclose($i2c);
```

$rtn got a value of "", so nothing was displayed.

I am aware that privileges are important here, so I am doing all under root user.

So I wonder, is PHP capable of getting and putting data to this kind of devices?

Comment: "I got nothing from that." - what does that mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase, that I got an empty variable, but no errors.

Comment: The whole point of "everything is a file on Unix" is that it behaves like a file. I suggest you check return values of functions used (`var_dump()` is better than `echo` since it won't cast to string, but you can just compare against documented return values) and double-check your PHP setup is configured to report errors. (I don't know what `/dev/i2c-1` is or whether it makes sense to write to it, but I take it for granted that it works when you do it from bash).

Comment: Did you try `i2cdetect -y 1` and `/usr/sbin/i2cget -y 1 ...` ?

Comment: Yes @MarkSetchell, I did that in bash with the library and it works. But he hole purpose of this is to know if there is a direct access through the /dev/i2c-1 from php.

Comment: I was trying to ascertain whether your devices were correctly attached, what devices they are, which address they appear at and whether other, standard tools could access them - rather than suggesting that you actually have to use `i2cget` in place of PHP.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález amigo, if you know any other method of accessing a character device in linux directly through the file system (bash,perl,node), I can try that. I haven't found any that works on /dev/i2c-1 on the raspberry.